# Numpy: сортировка двумерного массива по столбцу

Tags: python, массивы, сортировка, numpy

У меня есть двумерный массив и мне нужно его отсортировать по первому столбцу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я пробовал через это, но там выходные данные немного не такие:

```
database = sorted(database, key=lambda row: row[0])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие не такие?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2828059/7485582

Comment: Я показал на скриншоты какие они, там тип другой, наверное не сортировка через numpy

Comment: Ну там, видимо, список одномерных массивов получается. По ссылке выше смотрите решение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [122]: a = np.random.randint(10, size=(4,3))

In [123]: a
Out[123]:
array([[9, 1, 5],
       [0, 1, 7],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [4, 1, 3]])

In [124]: res = a[np.argsort(a[:, 0])]

In [125]: res
Out[125]:
array([[0, 1, 7],
       [3, 0, 1],
       [4, 1, 3],
       [9, 1, 5]])
```